# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct s_{
        int b;
}s;

int func1(s** ss){
        *ss->a = 10;
}
int func(s* t){
        func1(&t);
}
int main(){
        s a;
        func(&a);
        printf("\n a : %d \n",a.b);
        return 0;
}
```

Trying the sample program and getting an error with the o/p.

o/p:

```
[root@rss]# gcc d.c
d.c:6: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
d.c:9: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
d.c: In function ‘main’:
d.c:13: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
d.c:14: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
d.c:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
d.c:14: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: Are you forgot the `typedef` keyword before `struct`?

Comment: For one error, read about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). For another error, there's no member in the structure named `a`. For yet *another* error, `s` is a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You omitted the `typedef` that you need to declare your struct alias `s`.
2. The struct's member is `b` rather than `a`.
3. You failed to return anything from your functions. These should be void functions.
4. You need parens around `ss` in `func1`.
5. The parameterless `main` in `C` is `int main(void)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s_{
        int b;
}s;

void func1(s** ss){
        (*ss)->b = 10;
}

void func(s* t){
        func1(&t);
}

int main(void)
{
        s a;
        func(&a);
        printf("\n a.b : %d \n", a.b);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: 6. You should define main as int main(void) for clarity in C.

Answer (score 3):

After looking your code, it's clear that you missed `typedef` keyword before `struct`

```
struct s_{
        int b;
}s;
```

should be

```
typedef struct s_{
        int b;
}s;
```

and for

```
*ss->a = 10; //wrong.  operator precedence problem
             // `->` operator have higher precedence than `*`
```

There is no member name `a`. It should be

```
(*ss)->b = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown `s` is an object of type `struct s_`. You can't use it as a type in the function prototypes. Did you mean to introduce a type alias with `typedef`?